# strong parameters with has_many through and accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

This is my Model

```
class UnitPlate < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :unit_plate_components, :dependent => :destroy
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :unit_plate_components, :allow_destroy => true
   has_many :components, :through => :unit_plate_components
end
```

And this is the way i am writing the permitted_params

```
def unit_plate_params
  params.require(:unit_plate).permit(:name,:name_type,:type,:unit_plate_components_attributes => [:id, '_destroy',:component_id,:name,:type,:parent_id,:lft,:rgt,:depth])
end
```

**`It is complaining about this on save which is not saving my record`**

```
Unpermitted parameters: component_id, _destroy
Unpermitted parameters: name_type
```

**`This is the raw parameters`**

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CfGubZxXPW/7XEHEhnFTjKVKByNxGb5r3KJqoqoXHms=", "unit_plate"=>{"name"=>"okay", "name_type"=>"cool", "parent_id"=>"", "unit_plate_components_attributes"=>{"1375181809419"=>{"component_id"=>"181", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Create Unit plate"}
```

Any clue on what's going wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: that looks about right. How are you using `unit_plate_params` in your action ?

Comment: @FrederickCheung.. thanks for your reply.  I have placed the code in this GIST (https://gist.github.com/ankit8898/6112306) so that you can have a complete look.  there is something fishy with the `unit_plate_components_attributes` params which holds a key also.

Comment: Weird. Sure it's not something like defining that class on the fly confusing the rails code reloading?

Comment: @FrederickCheung, I did it the simple way of specifying directly under controller.. and it WORKED!  you were right `defining the class was confusing rails code reloading`.  Over engineering sucks ! Thanks!